# Mapping a Future[List[ObjectOne]] into Future[List[ObjectTwo]] with an inner list attribute - one call chain

Tags: scala, functional-programming, future

```
case class ObjectOne(id: String, numbers: List[Int])
case class ObjectTwo(id: String, numberOfFives : Int)

val start : Future[List[ObjectOne]] = ...
val end : Future[List[ObjectTwo]] = start. ?????
```

I am trying to turn the start object into the end object. End object should contain an id coming from ObjectOne and the number of times the digit 5 appeared on objectOne.numbers.

I can't find the way to write it in a simple call chain

Answer (score 3):

Let's suppose you have a convertion function which look like:

```
def objectOneToObjectTwo(one: ObjectOne): ObjectTwo = ???
```

Then `Future[List[_]]` converting would look like:

```
// put proper execution context or use global. It used in `Future#map` operation
implicit val ec: ExecutionContext = ???

val start : Future[List[ObjectOne]] = ???
val end : Future[List[ObjectTwo]] = start.map(_.map(objectOneToObjectTwo))
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Map fallowed by another map indicates one might consider a transformer such as [`Nested`](https://typelevel.org/cats/faq.html#listt), for example

```
val end = Nested(start).map { 
  case ObjectOne(id, numbers) => ObjectTwo(id, numbers.count(_ == 5)) 
}
```

[scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Vhcedwa9TnuJv6hjm3vzsg)